LM741 for audio amplifier with 8ohm 10W speaker
I've come across a circuit diagram for an audio amplifier using the LM741 op-amp, and I was wondering if this design would be sufficient to drive an 8-ohm, 10-watt speaker. If so, is there anything else I can do to improve it? If not, what should i change? Im thinking that the input would be mono

Several things wrong. You aren't the designer and I'm not going to ask a bunch more questions, then design and explain something else. So I'm leaving this for others. Best wishes.

Reasons not to use the 1968-vintage LM741

You have the design drawn in a simulator, so simulate it with the 8 ohm load. If you want improvements, then first see if it even needs improvements, or if it can even drive the load.

What are your component requirements? Can you use an LM386 instead?

R7. Change it to a few ohms, 5 or 10 perhaps, then see what your simulator does. Once you've done that, you'll see why we don't implement power amplifiers that single-ended way, and why we haven't used the 741 for the last 3 or 4 decades since better amplifiers became available.


I've come across a circuit diagram for an audio amplifier using the LM741 op-amp  --

Ignore it and keep on searching. That's not a good circuit.
Instead of wasting time trying to fix a bad circuit, spend time working with a good circuit, one that works the first time and you don't have to come asking for help.
https://us.startpage.com/do/dsearch?q=8+Ohm+speaker+audio+amplifier+circuit+LM386

While I agree with periblepsis, Davide and Andy on all points: Welcome here, Sigma! Your question got off to a bit of a rough start, hope you still feel at home here. Thing is: when you  copy someone else's circuit, it's kind of hard to help you if that other circuit isn't very good to begin with. And you found a really rather bad circuit, which doesn't even supply the one IC it contains wit a sufficient supply voltage. (and that choice of Opamp is terrible, on top of that).

(honestly, I'm not even sure how the LM741 could ever turn off Q1; LM714  is not a rail-to-rail opamp, its minimum output voltage is 2 V above its negative supply; so the base of Q1 is always at more than 0.7V than its emitter, so we're in saturation always? Strange. Find another circuit. This won't do, either way.)

@MarcusMüller: Why would you want to "turn off" Q1? In this circuit, it's functioning as an emitter follower, providing current gain only -- and isn't in saturation. (But it's still a terrible circuit overall.)

Connect C1, R1 & R2.

Why not use a modern Class-D amplifier like the PAM8610 10W+10W stereo or the 25-cent 3W PAM8403 ?

(@Spehro'speff'Pefhany: PAM8403 datasheet: "[clipping] will damage the device because of big gain")

You cannot produce 10 Wrms in an 8 ohm load with a total power supply voltage of 12 V.  Use Ohm's Law and Joule's Law to calculate the required supply voltage, then add at least 5 V for operating headroom.

It doesn't break your 10W speaker and surely you could hear something from the speaker, but it isn't anything that you expect to get from a properly designed and properly built 10W music amplification system.
Your output stage cannot pull the current which is needed to generate the full power audio from the negative half cycles of the audio signal. Negative half cycles are much more distorted than the positive ones. The transistor could push what's needed for well audible positive half cycles, but the 1000 ohm resistor R7 cannot do it for negative half cycles. The situation would be better if you wanted only one milliwatt instead of 10 watts.
My recommendation: Get some studying material how one constructs a class AB audio amplifier which has push-pull output stage. You seemingly know nothing of the subject.
Alternative: In theory you could replace the output capacitor with wire and get  a class A amplifier, but that dissipates continuously so much power that the transistor gets easily too hot. Also the speaker could get hot and at least it wouldn't give its best audio performance due the continuous DC current which in this case would be something between 750 and 1000 milliamperes depending on the actual DC resistance of the nominally 8 ohm speaker. R4 should be changed to a piece of wire. 2N3055 would require a driver transistor to keep the loading of the opamp reasonable. R1 and R2 should be connected also to the +input of the opamp. R5 and R6 are useless; remove them.
12V operating voltage and 8 ohm speaker need quite tricky amp construction (transformer or something else which essentially boosts the available voltage) to generate 10 W. Simple versions can in practice output only about 2 watts. That limitation can be seen easily by applying a couple of known laws, namely I=U/R and P=UI.

As comments have pointed out, there are multiple problems with this design. Here is a list of some of those problems.

The power supply voltage is inadequate to supply 10 watts through an 8 oh speaker. The rms voltage required for 10 w to pass through an 8 \$\Omega\$ speaker is

$$V_{rms} = \sqrt{P\times R} = \sqrt{ 10\times 8} = 8.944 \;\text{V}$$
The peak voltage is required is
$$V_{peak} = \sqrt{2} \times V_{rms} = 12.65 \;\text{V}$$
Even under ideal conditions, (which in reality won't apply), the 12 V supply is inadequate.

Using an emitter follower as an output stage, even if properly designed is horribly inefficient. Theoretically, the maximum efficiency of a fully class A (no clipping/distortion) capacitatively coupled emitter follower is 25%. In practices, to avoid distortion, it will be less.

R7 in your emitter follower is too large for significant undistorted output. You will either be limited to very much below the theoretical maximum output, or you will have horrible distortion. R7 should be of the same order of magnitude as the load, i.e. it should be somewhere in the vicinity of 8 \$\Omega\$, not 1 k\$\Omega\$.

The LM741 is a horrible op-amp for virtually any purpose.

The 2N3055 has a worst case \$\beta\$ of 20. That means that to drive over 1.6 A of emitter current, could require 80 mA of base current. The LM741 will not be able to handle that much current, nor will many other op-amps.



Let me add my voice to the chorus of "Don't do it!" with a few more observations. First, you are using a 741 in a single-supply 12-volt setup. Please be aware that "real" 741s aren't rated for that supply voltage. It's not that they cannot work at (effectively) +/- 6 volts, it's that you have no guarantee that they will. The originals were rated for +/- 15, and that was that. Later versions were rated for +/- 12, and current versions will talk about things like power supply rejection ratio at +/- 5 volts. But at your voltages there is simply no guarantee of the performance.
With that said, a modern 741 will usually work OK, by 741 standards, at +/- 6 volts. However, the 741 is not what is called a rail-to-rail output op amp. In fact a reasonable limit on output voltages is 3 volts less than the + supply and 3 volts more than the - supply. So your 741 cannot be depended on to put out more than a 6 volt swing with your power supply. That's about 2 volts rms, or about 1/2 watt into 8 ohms.
So your output buffer needs to be much more sophisticated than your class-A circuit. It needs to be capable of bipolar drive, so it can both source and sink current. It also needs a gain of at least two. Finally, it needs to provide a good deal more current than what you have.
On the other hand, if you cand provide such a buffer (high current and rail-to-rail output) you can make a so-so amplifier with your 12 power supply. It will look something like this

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
R1, R2 and OA1 produce what is called a virtual ground, in this case 6 volts. All the audio signals reference it.
C1 and R3 provide the signal input, and produce an AC audio signal around the virtual ground.
R4, R5 and OA2/BUF1 produce a high-current high-voltage version of the input. The gain of the stage is given by the ratio of RGAIN and R5.
R6, R7 and OA3/BUF produce an inverted version of the BUF1 signal.
So, lets say you have a +/- 1 volt signal input, and the input is at 1 volt.If RGAIN/R5 = 5, you get 5 volts at the top of your 8 ohm resistor. You also get -5 volts at the other end. For -1 volt in, you get -5 and +5. So a +/- 1 volt input will give +/- 10 volts at the load. +/- 1 volt is 0.707 rms, so the load sees 7.07 volts rms and will produce 6.25 watts. If you change the gain to 6, you get 9 watts.
This is close enough for government work, but note that it has no headroom at all. It makes unreasonable demands on the buffers, as they must provide an amp with zero voltage drop, and that is not something that happens in real life. A much more realistic number would be a volt less than the power supply, which implies a gain of 5. And that means 6 watts. To be fair, you can get very low voltage drops with power MOSFETs, but at your level of expertise I'm not willing to assume it.
Just for completeness sake, you could always put a 1-2 audio output transformer on the buffer outputs and get nearly 25 watts, but I'm assuming you aren't interested in that sort of circuit.
So, you can get something like what you want, but be aware that it won't be of great quality. The 741s are being operated at low gain, so bandwidth isn't an issue, but they are not designed for good high-speed crossover performance.
